# How to uninstall RVM in Ubuntu 18.04 completely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I tried uninstalling `rvm` in Ubuntu LTS 18.04 using the following command:

```
rvm implode
```

After uninstalling, I tried installing it again using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install rvm
```

But re-installation was unsuccessful and when I run `rvm` I get the following:

```
rvm: command not found
```

What are the steps to correctly remove `rvm`?

Comment: (After your update) Have you seen and followed these installation instructions? https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm#install -- In particular, logging out/in (or even a full reboot to be safe) might be helpful.

Comment: I was following this link. Since I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux, don't know how to enable this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know how to enable this"? Are you referring to step 2 of that link, which talks about "Change your terminal window"? I don't know if that's actually necessary on your specific setup; I would start by just trying a reboot. There are [other tutorials, specifically about installing RVM on Windows 10](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#ruby-rvm) that don't mention this.

Answer (score 1):

After the command `rvm implode` you should run `gem uninstall rvm` to make sure there's nothing left in your Ruby system install pointing to your rvm folder.

Usually, in order to remove what you have, `sudo apt-get remove rvm` should suffice, else try adding the `--purge` flag like in `sudo apt-get remove rvm --purge`. I understand you wanted to use the built-in command though. I don't know where you found the instructions you have followed, but it's weird that they didn't insist on the next step (uninstalling the gem).

For reinstalling, RVM has a dedicated Ubuntu package.
My advice is to do what I did to install it on my work computer, which was running Ubuntu. It's all listed [here](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm), but to take you through it:

1. Add the offical repository, update and install

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rvm
```

2. You'll have a group 'rvm' among your user groups. Add your user to it

`sudo usermod -a -G rvm <yourusername>`

In the link I included you'll find the instructions to have your terminal (assuming you're using Gnome as your Desktop Environment) login every time you reboot, enable local gems, install and change versions of Ruby and more.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official information](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) it souldn't work with just `apt-get`.

Visit [this page](https://rails.devcamp.com/trails/40/campsites/262/guides/comprehensive-guide-configuring-ruby-on-rails-postgres-development-environment-linux) and follow the steps.

Comment: I would advice using the documentation from the developers' git page, not a fan of third-party docs and tutorials, and I wouldn't use them as a source to point someone to on SO.